# z3 returns unknown when asserting division of 0 by 0 is 1

Tags: z3

I was trying out examples from the article [Z3: a tutorial](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.225.8231&rep=rep1&type=pdf). There is an example demonstrating that all functions are total, including "div":

```
(push)
(assert (= 1 (div 0 0))) 
(check-sat)
;sat (pop)
```

I noticed that z3 version 4.8.5 returns different results depending on whether one uses "push" or not.

With the code below, z3 returns unknown:

```
(get-info :version)
;(push)
(assert (= 1 (div 0 0)))
(check-sat)
```

The output from z3 is:

```
(:version "4.8.5 - build hashcode 8c085f1a1850")
unknown
```

In contrast, with the code below, z3 returns sat:

```
(get-info :version)
(push)
(assert (= 1 (div 0 0)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The output from z3 is:

```
(:version "4.8.5 - build hashcode 8c085f1a1850")
sat
(model 
)
```

In the [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide) tutorial, it says that "The command push creates a new scope by saving the current stack size", it seems that the usage of "push" should not cause different results here since there is only one assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking `unknown` and `sat` are not contradictory: The solver is allowed to bail out at any moment and say `unknown`. For instance, this sort of behavior can happen if you explicitly use tactics.

But you're absolutely correct that it's bizarre `push` is causing this discrepancy. Please file a ticket at the z3 github issues site: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and let us know what you find out!

Comment: Hi Levent, I will create a ticket for it. In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806141/keep-getting-unknown-result-with-pattern-usage-in-smtlib-v2-input?rq=1) the workaround is to use "push" before "check-sat" in order to get a model.Since I am also using the nightly build (4.8.5) as the other asker,  it makes me wonder if this has been as designed all the time.

Comment: Nice find! Indeed, if you use `push` z3 might pick a different solver; and this is certainly what's going on here. But I'd have still expected the regular solver to address this just fine: After all, non-incremental uses (i.e., those that don't contain `push`/`pop`) are quite common and I'm sure the z3 folks would appreciate seeing this example and making sure it can be solved out of the box.